# Nginx css and js 404

Tags: html, nginx

I have the below in my nginx file for a domain:

```
    location / {
            root /home/dpk/apps/abc/site;
            index index.html;
    }
```

When I access the domain, only the text is visible, all static files like favicon.ico, css and js files are giving a 404 error. As a result the layout is completely broken.

css is located in `/home/dpk/apps/abc/site/assets/home.css` and similarly js is stored in `/home/dpk/apps/abc/site/assets/home.js`.

The root directory is recursively owned by `www-data` and all files are `755`. This is a pure html website and no other language like php is being used.

I guess I am missing something in the configuration. Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you link the JS and CSS files? what path do you use?

Comment: I am linking in the html like `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.abc.com/favicon.ico">` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.abc.com/assets/home.css">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using just `root /home/dpk/apps/abc/site;` instead of the below.

```
location / {
        root /home/dpk/apps/abc/site;
        index index.html;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you do not need to use root in location, in fact it is a bad practice.